# Why should I add new user to Ubuntu before deploying web apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, web-deployment

I’m studying deploying rails app and all tutorials add new user before starting. Why should I add new user rather than just using root?

Reference
https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/16.04

Comment: Because it's `root`. The super-user. The user that can do anything they want on the system. See the issue?

Comment: Why are possible problems if I keep using root user?

Comment: ... Are you aware of what the `root` user is and has access to on the system?

Comment: Then what is the difference between sudoer and root?

Comment: A sudoer isn't root, they are temporarily *acting* as a root-ish user.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done for security, basically root user can do anything so it's risky.

"The root user is the administrative user in a Linux environment that has very broad privileges. Because of the heightened privileges of the root account, you are actually discouraged from using it on a regular basis. This is because part of the power inherent with the root account is the ability to make very destructive changes, even by accident."